# VSCode cmd+click on filename in terminal adds full path to search bar with "no matching results" displayed below

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I cmd+click a file path from the terminal, vscode puts the file in the search bar, but display **No matching results** below the search bar

I am able to go directly to the file if I delete the first part of the absolute path and make the file a relative path

I would like a way to go directly to the file by cmd+clicking the filepath in the terminal without needing to edit the filepath in the search bar

A recording of my problem is shown in the gif below

[image]

Comment: because the path is malformed. it's an absolute path missing a leading slash. what tool is producing/printing that error output?